# Redux deep clone - state is always equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

I have the following reducer in React Redux:

```js
export const reducer = (state = initialStateData, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case Action.TOGGLE_ARR_FILTER:
        {
          const subArr = state.jobOffers.filters[action.key];
          const filterIdx = subArr.indexOf(action.value[0]);
          const newArr = { ...state.jobOffers.filters
          };

          if (filterIdx !== -1) {
            newArr[action.key].splice(filterIdx, 1);
          } else {
            newArr[action.key].push(action.value[0]);
          }

          return {
            ...state,
            jobOffers: {
              ...state.jobOffers,
              filters: {
                ...newArr,
              },
            },
          };
        }
```

And this is my object:

```js
const initialStateData = {
  jobOffers: {
    filters: {
      employments: [],
      careerLevels: [],
      jobTypeProfiles: [],
      cities: [],
      countries: [],
    },
    configs: {
      searchTerm: '',
      currentPage: 1,
      pageSize: 5,
    },
  },
};
```

The reducer as such seems to work, it toggles the values correctly.

But: Redux always shows "states are equal", which is bad as it won't recognize changes.

Can someone help ? I assume that I am returning a new object..

Comment: May you can try [this](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper).

Comment: you have mutated state with splice and push , which means reference is still same, you have to change that with silce for a new copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you take a copy of `state.jobOffers.filters`, this still holds references to original child arrays like `employments`. So when you mutate `newArr[action.key]` with `splice` or `push`, Redux will not see that change, as it is still the same array reference.

You could replace this:

```
if (filterIdx !== -1) {
  newArr[action.key].splice(filterIdx, 1);
} else {
  newArr[action.key].push(action.value[0]);
}
```

with:

```
newArr[action.key] = filterIdx !== -1 
    ? [...newArr[action.key].slice(0, filterIdx), ...newArr[action.key].slice(filterIdx+1)]
    : [...newArr[action.key], action.value[0]]);
```

BTW, you don't have to copy `newArr` *again*, as it already is a copy of `filters`. You can replace:

```
filters: {
    ...newArr,
},
```

by just:

```
filters: newArr,
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use  [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) , redux also uses this for immutable updates for nested stuffs.
Because of this, you can write reducers that appear to "mutate" state, but the updates are actually applied immutably.

```
const initialStateData = {
  jobOffers: {
    filters: {
      employments: [],
      careerLevels: [],
      jobTypeProfiles: [],
      cities: [],
      countries: [],
    },
    configs: {
      searchTerm: '',
      currentPage: 1,
      pageSize: 5,
    },
  },
};
```

```
export const reducer = immer.produce((state = initialStateData, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case Action.TOGGLE_ARR_FILTER:

            const subArr = state.jobOffers.filters[action.key];
            const filterIdx = subArr.indexOf(action.value[0]);
            const newArr = state.jobOffers.filters;

            if (filterIdx !== -1) 
              newArr[action.key].splice(filterIdx, 1);
            else 
              newArr[action.key].push(action.value[0]);

            return state;
           }
          })
```